# Nexus in docker container how to configer another server as backup location in the tasks?

Tags: docker, backup, nexus, nexus3

I'm setting up Nexus as artifact manager for maven projects. I am using Nexus 3 in a docker container and I am trying to set a weekly backup as a task in the configuration area of Nexus. Unfortunately I cant find anything in the Nexus documentation about the options on how to set up the filesystem location for backup data. For example on the host filesystem or a different server. Can somebody help me please. A solution or an advice?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you've mounted a volume from your host to the nexus container you should be able to point your task configuration to the mounted volume from within the container. See this link for more details: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/backup-and-restore/configure-and-run-the-backup-task#app